# Mocking Service in Xamarin forms

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.forms, service, mocking, nunit

I have a xamarin forms app  where in the app constructor I have initialized called the a static class which initialaises the service

```
public App()
{
     Bootstrap.Start();
}
public class Bootstrap
{
        public static IServiceProvider container;

        public static void Start()
        {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton<IMyService,MyService>();
        container = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        MyService service = container.GetService(typeof(IMyService)) as MyService;
        }
    
}
```

In view model am getting the service like below

```
public class viewModel
{
  IMyService service;
   public viewModel(){
     service = Bootstrap.container.GetService(typeof(IMyService)) as MyService;
    }
 }
```

Now am creting Unit test with Nunit.
I am using **Autofac.Extras.Moq** to mock this viewmodel.I am getting object null error  in getting service (Bootstrap.container.GetService(typeof(IMyService)) as MyService;).

How to mock this kind of service?. I tried mocking up the bootstrap service in test setup.